# Date difference with custom format

Tags: php, datetime

I know there's a lot around here but for many articles I read and test this simply don't work..

I'm saving date with ACF like d.m.y and reading too.

When I make this type of comparison it works BUT only for the current month. No matter what I do, this is the working thing I've done that works, any advise please?

```
if(strtotime(date('d.m.y')) > strtotime($cd_date_from)) {
   $output .= ' class="event-passed"';
}
```

This means that I'm hiding only the event on the table row that the date is older than today (showing today).
If the date is 15.03.19 or 28.03.19 it shows BUT if it's 15.04.19 (other month) it don't.

Thank you in advance

Comment: so today is 15.03.09 that's why it is not working:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's much easier to use \DateTimeInterface to work with DateTime in php:
[\DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
<?php
$format = 'd.m.y';
$cd_date_from = '12.03.19';
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $cd_date_from);
$date->setTime(0,0,0,0);
if (new \DateTime() > $date) {
    echo 'hello';
}
```

Comment: according your reply the row with the today's date is not showing. The future ones and the yesterday's row yes.

Comment: DateTime object contain time also, so if you don't want to check time you can use $date->setTime(0,0,0,0); for example

Answer (score 1):

Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-), the date string is parsed as y-m-d.

To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Use:

```
if(strtotime(date('Y-m-d')) > strtotime($cd_date_from)) {
   $output .= ' class="event-passed"';
}
```

and pass `Y-m-d`  format values to `$cd_date_from`

Comment: I'm using Wordpress and on it I have this format too (with the country timezone), does your reply have solution based on this?

Comment: Why do you insist on working with `d.m.y` format? Just use `YYYY-MM-DD` format to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: design issues and client :)